# Repository - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, version-control

I am new to repositories and am currently looking around to find the best possible option.
I need something that can handle multiple versions of our website, and allow multiple collaborators to all push to the repo together.

Our current project is built in PHP, and we have a MySQL database.

I am short on funding and need the best option for our money.

I have limited ssh access to our server, however I have little to no experience working with repositories.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 3):

Also consider [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org).  And I would recommend Git or Mercurial over subversion.  Subversion is older and lacks capabilities you may find you'll want/need later on.

Comment: I have also been exploring all the available options. I agree mercurial and git look the most promising. I'm probably leaning toward Mercurial myself because netbeans supports it by default.

Answer (score 1):

Or Mercurial https://www.mercurial-scm.org/

An excellent Mercurial tutorial here:
http://hginit.com/ ;)

Comment: Zaf, I was looking at Mercurial, and I have just one main question, and that is do they support any MySQL databases? Or am I on my own when it comes to this.

Comment: Database structure for sure but as for the content I'll hand you over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306928/mysql-backup-with-mercurial

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'd want to learn either [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) or [Git](http://git-scm.com/). Both of those sites will have documentation for beginners. Given your requirements, it sounds like Git would be your best bet.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[Perforce](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/p4d.html) is pretty extensive and they have end user clients that are Java based, so it'll work in pretty much any OS.  I'm not going to claim it's the easiest, but we use it for our product which releases a new version every 3 weeks, and you don't have to make copies of the code for each separate version, you merely label the files to be a specific version.  We also use it to store our SQL changes, definition and initial values, along with the site's images, css, js, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using http://beanstalkapp.com, it is hosted subversion and GIT so you do not have to deal with the server side of things. It has worked great for us for the past 2 years.